# When does Westworld take place?

Tags: timeline, westworld-2016

The technology in *Westworld* on HBO seems to more advanced than our current technology, but ridiculously so. However, it has been mentioned by a few character that the park has been open for 30 years and had about 3 years of R&D before the front doors were open.

So while the technology my seem not too far out of reach for 2016, I feel that the technology in 1986 may not have been up to snuff. I am not looking for a "real world" explanation if the technology is possible. I am just wondering...

**Is the year in which the show takes place mentioned?**

Comment: We don't know...it's deliberately vague. It's also thought in some circles that we're actually watching two (or more) different timelines.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, it does seem that way as now the same hosts are appearing in different locations.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the host technology both hardware and software has been continually improved and updated over the 30+ years so it's probably right to assume **late** 21st Century for at least one timeline....but there's no reason to assume there isn't a later one also going on.

Comment: @Skooba - I've seen this whole "two timelines" nonsense on the reddit. Some users are absolutely obsessed with the idea, as if it's going to be the massive "***No, Luke, I am your father***" moment rather than something that'd leave 99% of the audience scratching their heads. I like the idea, but it's too clever and involved for network TV. As Philip J. Fry would say; "*[Clever things make people feel stupid and unexpected things make them feel scared](http://www.gotfuturama.com/Multimedia/EpisodeSounds/1ACV12/17.mp3)*"

Comment: @Valorum Are you up to date with episode 9? Not to start a whole discussion of recent plot events here, but I'd be curious to here your thoughts.

Comment: @Tobiasvl - I've only watched the first half. I'll watch the end tonight :-)

Comment: @Valorum I'm scared now.... :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We know it's set in the **"*21st Century*"**, thanks to an [inadvertent spoiler](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/10/02/westworld-premiere-interview) from showrunner Jonathan Nolan. Beyond that, the specific year hasn't (yet) been revealed.

> *"None of them [the hosts] understand that they're simply there for the
>   amusement of the 21st Century guests"*

Comment: Could have been a mistake.

Comment: @zabeus - It certainly could have been. He went on to say that we'd learn more about the outside world later in the season, so I guess we'll have confirmation soon enough.

Comment: That means that the GUESTS are from the 21sr century...

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens:   Ooh, ooh!   The 21st century guests are actually host androids in a  23rd century Worldworld park.

Comment: Shhhhh...you'll spoil everyone

Answer (score 8):

It takes place in the year 2052.

[image]

Here is the full-timeline:

http://www.businessinsider.com/when-is-westworld-taking-place-2016-12

Comment: Interestingly the footage you're referring to has been removed from the website and replaced with an identical video **missing the date**; http://delosincorporated.com/video/intra/ww_int_lockdown_feed_v08.mp4

Comment: Please summarise the linked page.